# How can I see git log in AOSP (Android Open Source Project) after repo sync done?

Tags: git, android-source, repo

Hi I'm trying to see git log each project under AOSP(Android Open Source Project).

At first the command `repo sync` is successfully done and I checked running emulator successfully after I built.

But I don't understand why I can't see git log It says

> fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

but `.git` is directly download by `repo sync` command so It should be work right? Is there anything have to do more to see git logs?

Here is a screen shot the root directory is `/aosp` which is `.repo` located and it's a external device(additional HDD).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a clean `repo sync`, and it works fine. Maybe something is wrong with your local copy/clone, maybe try it again from beginning within a different location.

[image]

Comment: Yeah you're right. I haven't any idea what was wrong but now it works! thanks.